# Angular2 price slider css based

Tags: angular

I am newbie in Angular2 and I want to try to transform Angular1x price slider into Angular2.

Angular1

http://plnkr.co/edit/aSWtPvG7mPN9eGHHOcRf?p=preview

**Angular2 me result**

```
https://embed.plnkr.co/VbsimfxfZWp4xa7dUpl3/
```

I am not able to run it and I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
Many thanks for your help.
Tony

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-change="change()" ng-model= "priceSlider.min"
```

should probably be

```
(change)="change()" [(ngModel)]="priceSlider.min"
```

I don't know what `rz-slider` is but

```
rz-slider-step="{{priceSlider.step}}"
```

might need to be changed to

```
attr.rz-slider-step="{{priceSlider.step}}"
```

or

```
[attr.rz-slider-step]="priceSlider.step"
```

(only if it causes an error message that `rz-slider-step` is not a property)

```
this.change = function() {
```

should be changed to

```
change() {
```

There is also no `$scope` in Angular2. Not shure what it is supposed to do in your example.

Comment: I made the changes but not working. rz-slider-step is a CSS Element. See in Plunker:                                                                            https://embed.plnkr.co/VbsimfxfZWp4xa7dUpl3/